# Catching Python exceptions similarly to signals

Tags: python, exception, signals

What I'm asking might not be possible, but it'd be quite helpful if it were.

Basically, I want to have a way to automatically capture any exceptions in a Python script and handle them a specific way, the way that I might catch a signal using a signal handler. It'd be something like

```
def except_handler(signo, frame):

  if signo == Exception:
    exception_cleanup()
```

I don't imagine there is an actual signal going on but that's sort of the functionality I'm going for, being able to handle exceptions program-wide without an explicit try/except clause. It'd be similar to using `trap ERR` in Bash. Is there any way of doing something like this in Python, or is try/except my only option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this (although I don't recommend it). Then filter on the type or value to handle the exception however you want. Generally anything you want to handle should go in a try/except/finally scenario and then filter on the exception types. Blindly catching all exceptions is usually a bad idea in most cases.

```
import sys

# Custom exception handler
def exception_handler(type, value, traceback):
    # Write whatever you want to
    print "Error Recognized"
    # Call the default exception hook
    sys.__excepthook__(type, value, traceback)


sys.excepthook = exception_handler
raise Exception("boop")



>> Error Recognized
>> Traceback (most recent call last):
>>     raise Exception("boop")
>> Exception: boop
```

Comment: Thanks! Good to know that there's actually a straightforward way of doing this. Definitely not something I want to make a habit of, but it's helpful to know this exists.